# SharePoint Search Index Journal file occupied 400GB space

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-search

We have SharePoint 2013 on premises with two search servers and search items are 20 Million.
Server 1 with primary index component is running fine and server 2 with index 
 replica component got degraded.
When checked for search status, it showing 'index out of sync and catching up' but it is running for more than 36 hours.

After checked the Journal file, it occupied 400 GB space it is continuously occupying more data and utilizing all disk space.

What could be the issue and how to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

The maximum capacity for single index partition in SP 2013 is 10 M items. You may want to look at re-partitioning your index if you are staying on 2013. 2016/2019 can handle 20M/partition.

[Software boundaries and limits for SharePoint 2013](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/install/software-boundaries-and-limits#overview-of-boundaries-and-limits)